# Need to change my code to generate correct JSON object

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jquery-tokeninput

I am trying to generate the following JSON to be accessed by tokenInput, but my code generates it in other way, how can I tailor the code to generate the correct JSON.

**Required Json**

```
get[{id:"set",name:"set"},{id:"object",name="object}]

or

   [{id:"set",name:"set"},{id:"object",name="object}]
```

**My JSON**

```
 {"get":[{"id":"set","name":"set"},{"id":"object","name":"object"}]}
```

MyCode

```
        JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("id","set");
        object.put("name", "set");
        jarray.add(object);

        JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject();
        object1.put("id","object");
        object1.put("name", "object");
        jarray.add(object1);

        res.put("get", jarray);
        return res;
```

**JSP**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#items").tokenInput("getOptions.jsp",{
            theme: "facebook"
            });
    });
```

Comment: Your JSON looks fine to me. Are you facing any problems with it?

Comment: @PradeepPati yes, token input cant read it, I need to change it to "required JSON" to be read by tokenInput.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"id":"set","name":"set"},{"id":"object","name":"object"}]
```

this can be only form can get instead of form ur code generates . make res a JSONArray . then try .. !

Comment: sorry I do not get you would you rephrase your answer